# Data size difference in SSIS output and SSMS output

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, etl

I have an SSIS package which extract data using SQL command from a database and then generate delimited text file which is `1452kb`

I run the same query on SSMS and generated text file which is `1499kb`

Both data gives same number of rows,what could be the reason behind the file size difference and way to resolve this

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the files are exactly the same? They may return the same number of rows but perhaps the data is different.

Comment: Maybe one file is in UTF-8 and the other isn't? Or maybe one file contains empty rows at the end? Or additional spaces at the end of each line? Finally, maybe it's something trivial like a different linebreak (char(10) in one file and char(13)+char(10) in the other file? Open both files in a decent editor and switch the hidden characters on - this should help clarify the issue.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible set of steps so that we can identify the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the files contains the same data. There are many things that can make size different:

- **Encoding:**
  If using Unicode it may store additional data like [The byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
- **Row Delimiter:**
  It's really just about which bytes are stored in a file. `CR` is a bytecode for carriage return (from the days of typewriters) and `LF` similarly, for line feed. It just refers to the bytes that are placed as end-of-line markers. `CRLF` is the combination of the two character.
- **Empty Rows:**
  Sometimes data exporter may add empty Rows at the End of the file
- **Header:**
  If one file contains columns header and the other doesn't

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here's an even more surprising difference in bytes between my old and new laptop, when running a simple perf test from an Azure SQL database:

```
 SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM [Order] ORDER BY OrderId DESC
```

Old laptop: `348,057,200 bytes`
New laptop: `523,447,600 bytes`

That's 50% more data being transmitted for the same exact data.

- Both Windows 11
- Same database, (yes I'm 100% sure of this)
- New laptop SSMS 20, Old laptop SSMS 18.12

Whatever the exact reason will have to remain a mystery for now. Very odd though.